# Quais destas expressões com o verbo "Tirar" são usadas em português europeu?

Tags: português-europeu, significado-em-contexto, expressões-idiomáticas

1. Tirar de tempo
2. Tirar uma dúvida
3. Tirando isso
4. Tirar de letra
5. Tirar de casquinha
6. Tirar de férias
7. Tirar onda
8. Tá me tirando?
9. Tirar um pensamento da cabeça
10. Tirar uma música
11. Tirar provisto
12. Tirar um fino

Answer (score 3):

Em português europeu só são usadas as seguintes frases:

> 2 . Tirar uma dúvida
>
> 3 . Tirando isso
>
> 9 . Tirar um pensamento da cabeça
>
> 10 . Tirar uma música
>
> 12 . Tirar um fino

Algumas outras são típicas do português brasileiro mas seria muito estranho serem usadas no português europeu:

> 5 . Tirar de casquinha
>
> 8 . Tá me tirando?

---

---

As seguintes penso terem erros ortográficos:

> 1. Tirar de tempo

Penso que deve ser *"Tirar o tempo"* o que significa *"medir o tempo"* ou *"roubar o tempo (a alguém)"* em português europeu.

> 3. Tirando isso

Outra maneira de dizer: *"Excepto isso"*.

> 4 . Tirar de letra
>
> 10 . Tirar uma música

Em português europeu estas duas parecem equivalentes, *"tirar uma música"* é a expressão que os músicos usam para transcrever a [pauta musical](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauta_(m%C3%BAsica)) de uma música que estão a ouvir... *"Tirar de letra"* pode ser um erro tipográfico porque *"tirar uma letra"* seria o equivalente e significa transcrever a [letra músical](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letra_(m%C3%BAsica)) -portanto o texto que é cantado na música- de uma música que se está a escutar.

O @stafusa comentou que no Brasil

> 4. tirar de letra

significa fazer muito bem, e.g., *"Ele tirou de letra a prova."*

> 11. Tirar provisto

Talvez seja um erro tipográfico, [provisto parece não estar no dicionário](https://dicionario.priberam.org/provista).

> 12. Tirar um fino

Significa isto (o copo da cerveja alto e fino é chamado *"fino"*):

[image]

Comment: "Tirar um fino" continua a ser só no Porto e talvez zona norte, não? Cá por baixo, só ouvi "tirar um imperial". Entretanto, pelos vistos no Brasil, "tirar um fino" significa (um carro) passar de rasante.

Comment: @Jacinto zona centro também é *"fino"*, não tenho a certeza se de Leiria para sul começam a dizer imperial mas pelo menos até Coimbra todos dizem *"fino"*.

Comment: @stafusa acrescentei o comentário.